# how to pass the function use query builder by mockery in phpunit laravel

Tags: laravel, phpunit, mockery

**Function service**

```
public function setAreaCommissionInfo()
{
    DB::table('shell_work_ci')->truncate();
    DB::table('shell_work_result')->truncate();

    $sql = File::get(storage_path(self::INSERT_SHELL_WORK_CI));
    DB::unprepared($sql);

    $sql = File::get(storage_path(self::INSERT_SHELL_WORK_RESULT_AREA));
    DB::unprepared($sql);
}
```

***Function test***

```
public function testSetAreaCommissionInfo()
{
    DB::shouldReceive('table')
        ->times(2)
        ->andReturn(collect(array
            (
                (object)
                    [
                        'id'=>1,
                        'corp_id'=>2,
                        'genre_id'=>3,
                        'prefecture'=>4,
                        'affiliation_area_stat_id'=>'',
                        'commission_count_category'=>6,
                        'created'=>'0',
                        'created_user_id'=>0
                    ]
            ))
        );
    DB::shouldReceive('truncate')
        ->times(2)
        ->andReturn(collect(array
            (
                (object)[]
            ))
        );
    DB::shouldReceive('unprepared')
        ->times(2)
        ->andReturn(true);
    $this->affiliationAreaStatService = new AffiliationAreaStatService(
        $this->mCorpCategoryRepository,
        $this->affiliationAreaStatRepository,
        $this->commissionInfoRepository
    );
    $result = $this->affiliationAreaStatService->setAreaCommissionInfo();
    $this->assertNull($result);
}
```

*I can't pass **DB::table('shell_work_ci')->truncate() && DB::table('shell_work_result')->truncate()**. I tried many ways but still not successful. I can not find many documents.Can you give me little documents on this issue.Thanks*

Comment: The answer : DB::shouldReceive('table->truncate')
                            ->times(2)
                            ->andReturn(true);